# Sql 2016 STD SP1 Always On with DB Mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, mirroring

I have 2 standard editions of sql 2016 sp1.
Since only 1 dB is allowed for always on I have to setup other 4 db’s in db mirroring.

My always on endpoint is already using port 5022.
Is there a place in db mirroring where I can change 5022 to let’s say 7022?

Thank you

Comment: I’m having trouble here. Why is 1 Availability Group + 4 mirrored databases better than 5 Availability Groups?

Comment: Guys it’s not better it’s just the 4 other db’s are TFS and we thought using db mirroring would be sufficient.
Thank for all your replies

Answer (score 2):

> Since only 1 dB is allowed for always on I have to setup other 4 db’s in db mirroring.

That makes absolutely no sense as they work *basically* the same way. Yes, there are some very real differences between them, but if someone told me "this works for mirroring but can't be used in availability groups" I'd ask why. the capture mechanism is *roughly* the same, the transfer mechanism is *roughly* the same, and the apply mechanism is *roughly* the same. When I say "roughly" I mean they are not 100% identical.

*I'd* put them all in AGs.

> My always on endpoint is already using port 5022. Is there a place in db mirroring where I can change 5022 to let’s say 7022?

No, because there can only be a single mirroring endpoint which is what **both** availability groups and mirroring uses. The reason that it's called a "mirroring" endpoint and not an "availability group" endpoint is two fold. First, mirroring came first. Second, if the name was changed it could cause a compatibility issue with older applications and code where the keyword would change, so they won't change it due to backwards compatibility.

I'd be happy to understand why someone is saying that a database can belong to mirroring but not belong to an availability group.

Comment: Sean this is standard edition and I cannot have 4 db’s in 1 AG group.

Comment: No, but you can have 4 different AGs with a single database in it which is no different than mirroring which is only a single database. @AlexSQL